# load all javascript files from style library in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

i have some JQUERY UI script files located in a style library,from style library some scripts are loading in custom master page they are

```
    <script src="/Style%20Library/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"  type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/Style%20Library/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/Style%20Library/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/Style%20Library/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/icons1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/icons2.js"></script>
```

> here bootstrap scripts files are not loading and remaining are loading.in content page am calling these scrits files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/prettify.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/animo.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/jquery.inview.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/jquery.tipsy.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/jquery.ui.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/superfish.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/custom.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/about/sscr.js"></script>
```

> these are all loading . only those 2 scripts  are not loading .

Comment: are you trying to get the js files to load from masterpage? but they dont?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the other way around, only two scripts should load based on your markup. This is because browsers won't handle your self-closing of `script`-tags. Instead you should use `</script>` for all the scripts.

If your browser is telling you that two scripts are not loading these scripts are probably, `icons2.js` and `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` since the first one should always be interpreted correctly and icons2 is after the last correct `</script>`. If you get errors on these it is simply because the path is wrong or they don't exist, while your other script references don't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SharePoint 2013,  please make sure that "Minimal Download Strategy" feature is turned off in the site features.  this should help you in loading all the script files

Comment: Am using sharepoint 2010 foundation